# How to round the corners of a card (body and image) in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive web interface for a mock "recipe app". Currently im using bootstrap 4 and i'm having trouble with customizing my card element to match my wireframe.

Wireframe card: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbDFR.jpg

Current card in browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0m7M.jpg

I've managed to "fix" the border radius of my card image with a custom css

```
.img-rounded{
    border-radius: 20%;
}
```

However, I still need to make my card element rounded (like the picture of the wireframe). What's the best way of doing this?

Card HTML:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="./assets/img/1.jpg" class="card-img-top " alt="Jelo 1">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">Recipe name</h5>
                    <p class="card-text mb-4">Some quick example text to build on the Recipe name and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <div class="container mb-2">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill" style="background-color: #32BF84;">Open</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill" style="background-color: #32BF84;">Edit</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill" style="background-color: #32BF84;">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: please share you html code so that I can help then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simple and can be achieved by simple CSS only.
Just as you have added `border-radius` to the image you have to add the same to the parent element also which holds the content and images...

Let's say you have `<div class="card">`, inside it you have `<div class="content">`, and then you have your image,
So kindly try adding the same `border-radius` to `<div class="content">` as well. It should solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the same rule `border-radius: 20%` to the card element.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! Adding `border-radius: 20%` helped!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same CSS border to both the classes i.e. `<div class="card">` and `<div class="content">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-radius , and hide the overflow

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem; border-radius: 20px; overflow: hidden;">
```